# How to add the date to file name while uploading a file to s3 bucket using alteryx

Tags: amazon-s3, alteryx

I have a workflow in alteryx where I am downloading two files from two different urls. After making the required modifications I want to upload them to the s3 bucket as well as save a copy locally. I want to add the current date while saving the file in both cases. I was successful in using a formula tool to rename the file saved locally. But unable to do for the copy being uploaded to s3. Can anyone help me with this? PS: Since it's the company data I cant share the screenshot of the workflow.

Comment: Ask your AWS people to set up a storage gateway: (https://aws.amazon.com/storagegateway). You write your output to it like a normal file path, and then it magically shows up in S3.

Comment: Any Alteryx workaround possible? Since my supervisor asked me to find a solution in Alteryx.

Comment: Review the S3 Upload Tool here: `https://community.alteryx.com/t5/Alteryx-Designer-Knowledge-Base/Tool-Mastery-Amazon-S3-Upload-and-Download/ta-p/344598`.